# Uninstall official lollipop Samsung Galaxy s5

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, crashes, uninstallation

Yesterday, I installed android Lollipop on my Samsung Galaxy s5. It was an offical update, since I dont like to flash my device, because it is a work mobile.

However, this offical lollipop release from Samsung keeps crashing. It crashes while the screen is off and I want the turn it on again. The indicator LED flashes and the device reboots. This doesn´t happen every time, but it does happen extremely often. So my phone is unworkable.

I cleaned the cache partition of the device but this did not help. So to remedy this problem, I want to uninstall lollipop and revert back to Kitkat. However, when I do a factory reset, it will only whipe my personal data, not the update.

What should I do?

Comment: You can't revert to an older version of Android I'm afraid. Normally I'd say you can, using a custom ROM, but I wouldn't recommend that for a work device at all. To be honest, returning it to the retailer may be the only option. Since you have factor reset, wiped cache etc, there's not much else that I can think of.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will talk to my boss about sending it back.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, with Odin! Done it couple of times, but unfortunately it will start to download the Lollipop update again and will continue to keep asking you to install it. :(

Comment: Could you expand your answer by explaining *how to do that on Odin*?

Comment: Odin is a tool to flash your ROM, you can't downgrade the OS with it, like you are asking.

Comment: Odin can be used to install official Samsung ROMs. I used it multiple times, on the S2 and de S4. If you have the right official ROM (download from Sammobile.com or other sites that have it) and you should be able to upgrade or downgrade to any version! There are more than enough tutorials online that show how to do it. In short: Boot phone to download mode, connect to PC, open Odin and check if the device is recognized, press the PDA button, select your ROM, press OK/Install (not sure what the Install button is called from the top of my head)

Answer (score 1):

Without flashing your device to a new ROM completely, there is no way to "downgrade" a device to a previous version.

You can completely re-flash your phone, or  you will have to wait for updates to fix your existing OS.

Bottom line, there is NO downgrade path possible without performing a complete reflash of your device.